# Segmentation Fault in Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, segmentation-fault

I have this assembly code:

```
00000000 <Q2>:
   0:   55                      push   %ebp
   1:   89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
   3:   83 ec 20                sub    $0x20,%esp
   6:   c7 45 fc 1f 00 00 00    movl   $0x1f,-0x4(%ebp)
   d:   c7 45 f8 06 f4 ff ff    movl   $0xfffff406,-0x8(%ebp)
  14:   8b 45 fc                mov    -0x4(%ebp),%eax
  17:   8b 55 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%edx
  1a:   8d 04 02                lea    (%edx,%eax,1),%eax
  1d:   89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
  20:   8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
  23:   0f af 45 f4             imul   -0xc(%ebp),%eax
  27:   89 45 f0                mov    %eax,-0x10(%ebp)
  2a:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
  2d:   8b 55 f0                mov    -0x10(%ebp),%edx
  30:   8d 04 02                lea    (%edx,%eax,1),%eax
  33:   89 45 ec                mov    %eax,-0x14(%ebp)
  36:   83 7d ec 00             cmpl   $0x0,-0x14(%ebp)
  3a:   74 0a                   je     46 <Q2+0x46>
  3c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
  41:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
  43:   89 45 f4                mov    %eax,-0xc(%ebp)
  46:   8b 45 f8                mov    -0x8(%ebp),%eax
  49:   89 c2                   mov    %eax,%edx
  4b:   c1 fa 1f                sar    $0x1f,%edx
  4e:   f7 7d 08                idivl  0x8(%ebp)
  51:   c9                      leave  
  52:   c3                      ret
```

I thought the segmentation fault was on line 4e where it would divide by the `%edx` after it has been shifted right by `0x1f (31)` in decimal. I figured that answer would most likely result in a division by `0` unless the number was greater than or equal to `2^31`.

I have been informed that whether or not the segmentation fault occurs depends on the value of the 1 parameters of the function. Upon further inspection of the assembly code I have come to the conclusion that the fault is not dependent on the parameter. I can't seem to find what I've overlooked. Can anyone help?

Comment: Line 41 looks like a segfault to me.

Comment: @FrankKotler if this is `objdump` output of an object file, line 41 may have an invisible relocation entry. @John if so, can you use `-dr` switches?

Comment: A segmentation fault _cannot_ be line `4e` unless you got a corrupted framepointer (`%ebp`) register. That's because division-by-zero causes `SIGFPE` with a `siginfo_t` having `si_code == FPE_INTDIV`. Nothing in your function can corrupt `%ebp`, so if a `SIGSEGV` occurs on _that_ line, you either have a very buggy signal handler / home-grown context switcher (the only userspace entities capable of changing `%ebp`), or a kernel bug (unlikely). Use 'gdb' to do an `info reg` / `disas $eip-20 $eip+20`. Also - your code is unoptimized compiler output. Source, please, to justify the "C" tag ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with these lines:

```
3c:   b8 00 00 00 00          mov    $0x0,%eax
41:   8b 00                   mov    (%eax),%eax
```

You are moving 0 into `%eax` and then trying to access the memory at `(%eax)`. On many operating systems (linux, for example), attempting to read address `0x0` will result in a Segmentation Fault.

If I'm reading the code correctly, this will happen unless `param * (param + 31) == 3066`, which could occur if `param` is -73 or 42.